# Why custom launcher icon keep pulsing?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I created a custom launcher icon to enable/disable the touch feature of my Lenovo X220 Tablet.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=handsoff
Comment=Enable / Disable touch feature
Exec=thinkpad-touch
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/apps/preferences-desktop-keyboard-shortcut\
s-symbolic.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

If I click on it, it launch the command successfully, but then it **keep pulsing for 5 seconds**, and it is impossible to launch the command again to re-switch.

Why does it keep pulsing? The command is executed immediately!
How can avoid this?

Comment: I'm guessing the other icons don't do this.. Could it be because things are taking a bit to finalize in the background?

Comment: Uhm, no... the command is instantaneous if given in the terminal

Comment: Thye cause is probably not in Unity, but in the script that enables / disables the touch feature (`thinkpad-touch`). Is it a "home made" script?

Comment: It is a package from the ` ppa:martin-ueding/stable` repository. When launched in a terminal, it ends very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Its the launcher icon animation on Launching program you can change it with 'Unity tweaks tool' or 'compiz configuration manager' i prefer Unity tweaks tool because compiz is far advanced one and selecting anything wrong may cause os problems

Unity tweaks tool => Unity => Launcher => icons => launch animations

Comment: Anyway it is strange because if, for example, I use the terminal icon to launch a terminal, it does not pulse as the opening is very fast.